# Unable to identify a Kanji

Tags: kanji

I just can't figure this Kanji from an old newspaper out, I am guessing it is a printing style not used anymore.I was trying to go by the 3-character radical on the left but I can't find anything that includes the 2 strokes in the middle.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is 「派{は}」 meaning a "faction", "group", "school", etc.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that it could be an enclosure.

Comment: That looks like a horrible font for a newspaper to use.. To my eyes anyway. 0_0 I was stumped.

Comment: ^ 大正か昭和初期の新聞広告のフォントみたいですね。「懐映体」っていうんですかね　http://tande.jp/lab/2012/09/1887

Comment: @strongfish91, it's not an enclosure character.  The radical is the three-strokes **氵** version of **水**, and the body of the character is ****, originally derived as the mirror of **永**.  More at the Wiktionary entries for [**派**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B4%BE), [**氵**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B0%B5), and [****](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A0%82%A2#Chinese).